# Access <input type='file'> properties from webpage in popup

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

In a webpage I have a `<input type='file'>` tag. After a file is selected I pass it from a content script to the popup script via background script.

Then I try to access the `length` property of the file list (in the popup). The error `Error: Permission denied to access property "length"` is thrown.

How can I fix it? Do I need special permissions?

I use Firefox 55.0.3 (64-bit).

---------Code---------

content.js

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')
nodes.forEach(node => {
  node.onchange = event => browser.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'changed', files: event.target.files})
})
```

background.js

```
let files
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.type === 'changed') files = message.files
  if (message.type === 'request_files') sendResponse({files: files})
})
```

popup.js

```
browser.runtime
  .sendMessage({type: 'request_files'})
  .then(response => console.log(response.files.length)) // Error here!
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

test.html (to test the extension)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add relevant parts of the code: how you pass it around and how you try to access it.

Comment: @Xan code added. See `popup.js` where the error occurs.

Comment: I am honestly surprised it even made that far. `sendMessage` shouldn't be able to send a `FileList` or `File` across. What exactly do you need in the popup? Can you extract this data in the content script and pass it to the popup as something JSON-serializable?

Comment: Would be much more code that way because I must call from `background.js` to `popup.js` again and again. But the code won't look bad so I would accept this as an answer.